# kubernetes export ports

Tags: port-forwarding, kubernetes

I would like to bind my service on all nodes to ports 80 and 443, so that I will be redirected via a DNS name (kubernetes) to any node that redirects me directly to the service via HTTP/S and then to the deployment (nginx). However, I don't know exactly how this works, because the range of the NodePorts only goes from 30000 to 32xxx.

Here is my setup

```
DNS-Name      IPv4
k8s-master    172.25.35.47
k8s-node-01   172.25.36.47
k8s-node-02   172.25.36.8
kubernetes    172.25.36.47
kubernetes    172.25.36.8
```

My yaml-file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: proxy
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 80     
    port: 80            
    protocol: TCP      
    targetPort: 80     
  - name: https
    nodePort: 443     
    port: 443           
    protocol: TCP       
    targetPort: 443     
  selector:
    name: proxy
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: proxy
  labels:
    name: proxy
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: proxy
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
     labels:
       name: proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
          protocol: TCP
```

Which type of service provide me a function to expose this ports or how I can realize my mental setup?

Volker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. simple port forwarding
2. externalIPs
3. keepalived

## Simple port forwarding

Run the following on all servers

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports <nodeport>
sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -o lo --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports <nodeport>
```

replace `<nodeport>` with the port you choose for nodeport. This requires you to run a command on all machines, and is a bit hacks. A better solution would be:

## externalIps

[link to docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips)

This allows you to bind any port on a specific node, which will then be routed through the cluster. This does provide a single point of failure, obviously, which can be fixed with:

## keepalived

keepalived is a very simple piece of software. It creates a virtual IP address, which is moved to point to a different node when the master fails. It effecively creastes an alias IP address for the master keepalived server. A good start would be [keepalived-vip](https://github.com/aledbf/kube-keepalived-vip), which automatically sets up keepalived for services you give it.

## conclusion

I personally use keepalived-vip for this, as it fits my network model much better, but if your clients can access any of your servers, then simple port forwarding is the only way to go about it.